# Swiper not working on browser is resized to Smartphone view in chrome

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm having some issue now in my swiper. I'm currently on test phase and my swiper is not working when the window is changed to smartphone and I have to refresh my browser to make the swiper work again. Is there any way I can re initialize my swiper to adapt to the new browser type? Here's what I have:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    effect: 'slide',
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    simulateTouch: true,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    on: {
        slideChangeTransitionEnd:function() {
            //other codes
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried

```
setTimeout(() => {
    swiper.update()
}, 500)
```

and

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   swiper.reInit()
})
$(window).trigger("resize")
```

but they are all not working. Can you help me figure out what I'm missing? or is it really needed to refresh the page to make the js adapt to its new browser environment?

Slider only works if clicking the previous or next button but not on drag.

Comment: Someone has any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let resize = function () {
    // Whatever you like to do
}

window.onresize = resize
```

You can read more about resize event here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize

Comment: unfortunately, when I put `swiper.update()` in my resize function, swiper is still not working.